# Unable to resolve String.String when trying to invocate class in runtime

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I have a nuget package and a service consuming that package.

In the package:
TestObject.cs

```
//construcor
public TestObject(IAnotherObject anotherobject, string val)
{
//do something
}
```

In the service: 
I register IAnotherObject via Dependency Injection.

```
services.AddSingleton<ITestObject,TestObject>();
services.AddSingleton<IAnotherObject,AnotherObject>();
```

Now, when I run the service, I get an error:
 **Unable to resolve String.String when trying to invocate TestObject (from nuget package class).**
Basically, it is unable to resolve the `val` parameter at runtime.

When I remove it from the parametrized constructor, the error doesn't show up. 
Anything specific that can be done?
Thanks.

Comment: Will the `val` string be known at compile time, or is it a runtime value?

Comment: It will be determined in the runtime and that val is basically the current user logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor for `TestObject` expects a second parameter named `val` of type `String`.

The container is trying to instantiate your class and in the process, it's looking to provide an instance of type `String` to fulfill the requirements of the constructor. It looks in its internal registry and cannot find such binding, hence the error.

Because the value is known at runtime, you need a factory pattern. I would suggest implementing another injected service that provides the information needed (e.g. `ISecurityManager`), then configure the factory method to provide this value:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAnotherObject, AnotherObject>();
services.AddSingleton<ISecurityManager, SecurityManager>();
services.AddSingleton<ITestObject, TestObject>((provider) => 
{
    var user = provider.GetService<ISecurityManager>().GetCurrentUserName();
    return new TestObject(provider.GetService<IAnotherObject>(), user);
});
```